# Functional equation and whether the function is constant

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, functional-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that for any pair $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}$ the following holds:
$$f(x+1,y)=f(x,y+1)=f(2x+y,x+y)=f(x,y)$$ Then if $f$ is continous, is it true that $f$ is constant?

And the second one, if $f$ is lebesgue integrable then it is constant almost everywhere?

I think both is true because this function is multi periodic but I don't know how to get it derictly from the equations above, can someone help?

Comment: The function is defined from $f:[0,1]^2\to\mathbb{R}$. Can you prove that $f$ is bounded on the unit square?

Comment: @Bumblebee I didn't quite understand why does it imply that the function is constant

Comment: Since the function is periodic with period $1$ in both variables, you just need to investigate the behaviors of the function in $[0,1]^2.$ Now since $f(2x+y,x+y)=f(x,y),$ find all the points in $[0,1]^2$ that you can reach starting from $(x,y).$ These are exatly 
   $$ \begin{pmatrix}2&1\\1&1\\ \end{pmatrix} ^n \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\\ \end{pmatrix}$$ and on those points your function is constant. "I think", by passing to the grid of rational numbers we can reach all the rational points and it will conclude the proof of first part.

Comment: It is enough to prove that the area-preserving map $T(x,y) := (2x+y, x+y)$ is ergodic. (This is the Arnold's cat map, and it is known that it is ergodic.)